# Integrating your public/css files in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Please Help me check if I make any error in my code, because the app.css files is not working.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
var posts = [
    {title: "Once upon a time", author: "Richard"},
    {title: "The Way", author: "Ikoro"},
    {title: "I Love Critics", author: "Emmanuel"},
    {title: "Adorable Bunny", author: "Christian"}
]
res.render("posts", {posts: posts});
});
```

This is my public directory with the app.css files in it

```
body {
background: #ffff00;
color: #800080;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your view/template code?

Comment: Also can you just navigate to `http://localhost:4000/app.css` and tell us what happens?

Comment: I navigated to the url and it showed that same codes on the particular file and this is it.. body {
    background: #ffff00;
    color: #800080;
}

Comment: Nope that's not an answer but for westdebestdb

Answer (score 0):

Please westdabestdb look at the view/template code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/app.css">
<h1>The Post Page</h1>

<!-- for Loop Syntax for Embedded JavaScript Templates -->
<% for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){ %>
<li>
    <%= posts[i].title %> - <strong><%= posts[i].author %></strong>
</li>
<% } %>

<!-- forEach Loop Syntax for Embedded JavaScript Templates -->
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
<li>
    <%= post.title %> - <strong><%= post.author %></strong>
</li>
<% }) %>
```